# Tomcat not finding project's welcome page after converting to maven

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

Long story short, the server where we had all our libraries and other goodies got infected by a virus so we decided to try out maven as a way to handle all the dependencies, so I'm testing it out with a project I'm working on.

The project is a myfaces+primefaces web application, and after getting everything together and getting the pom.xml up, I gave it a shot, deployed it on my tomcat and I get a 404 when it tried to load up the welcome page. I think I got the project structure right, but while moving stuff to make it maven compliant I fucked something up and neither me nor any of the guys around can see what's wrong (aka they cba to help out).

This is the contents of the web.xml of the project (the welcome page is at the end):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<display-name>Servlet 3.0 Web Application</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Production</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.SUBMIT</param-name>
        <param-value>partial</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>gp</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.CLIENT_WINDOW_MODE</param-name>
        <param-value>url</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.CACHE_EL_EXPRESSIONS</param-name>
        <param-value>noCache</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.STRICT_JSF_2_FACELETS_COMPATIBILITY</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.EARLY_FLUSH_ENABLED</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.NUMBER_OF_SEQUENTIAL_VIEWS_IN_SESSION</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.NUMBER_OF_VIEWS_IN_SESSION</param-name>
        <param-value>100</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!--    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.PUSH_SERVER_URL</param-name>
        <param-value>http://localhost:8080</param-value>
    </context-param>-->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>carpetas.FUENTES</param-name>
        <param-value>/usr/share/fonts</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>carpetas.FUENTES_TRUETYPE</param-name>
        <param-value>/usr/share/fonts/msttcore</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>carpetas.TEMP</param-name>
        <param-value>/usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.69/temp</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>activeDirectory.ldap.nombreServidor</param-name>
        <param-value>atlante</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>activeDirectory.ldap.nombreDominio</param-name>
        <param-value>intranet.com</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
        <param-value>auto</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>forceUTF8CharSet</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>utf-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>forceUTF8CharSet</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <!--    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>-->
    <!--    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>-->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <resource-env-ref>
        <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>180</session-timeout>
        <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>inicio.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And this is the project structure for the web content

[image]

If you guys need any other info ask for it and I'll add it to the question, thanks in advance.

Comment: Try changing welcome filelist attribute to `<welcome-file>/WEB-INF/inicio.xhtml</welcome-file>`

Answer (score 0):

If application is not compiled or is compiled but not deployed to Tomcat correctly, 404 is normal.

Comment: The application is compiled, deployed and started on tomcat, the 404 is not that it doesn't find the context, but that it doesn't find the welcome page, the `inicio.xhtml` file, which is listed in the web.xml